# How to put a Winform application inside installation kit?

Tags: winforms, installation

I want my application to be inside installation kit and after the installation create shortcut icon on my desktop, how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easyiest way would to use the [Visual Studio Setup Wizard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wx3b589t.aspx) Project assuming you are using Visual Studio. There are other options such as [WIX](http://wix.codeplex.com/) , [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) and [Install Shield LE](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) which is an option in VS2010 it will be replacing the Visual Studio Installer in later versions of Visual Studio.

Comment: @falukky I added some additional links and info.

Comment: finally i decided to use Inno Setup, is it possible to add another exe files to my installation kit ?

Comment: @falukky Yes it is, I do not personally use Inno Setup but looking at their documentation it appears you just need to add them to the File section.